# Android Webview Custom user agent is getting reset when a new tab is opened in the website

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using the following code to set custom user agent for webview:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        String code = "customuseragent";
        String newUserAgent = mWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
         newUserAgent += (" " + code);
         newUserAgent += (" " + code);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUserAgent);
}
```

This works fine when the app is opened and the initial url is loaded. However, when any page opens a link in new tab via `target="_blank"` or JS handling, the user agent gets reset to the default one. `setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically` and `setSupportMultipleWindows` are set as `false`. How to prevent the user agent string from getting reset to default in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening due to this restriction by chrome as stated [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/webview/#how-do-i-set-the-user-agent-of-the-webview):

> You can't set the user-agent string used for XMLHttpRequests made from
> JavaScript. Those requests always use the default user-agent string.